# In Linux, is working as su the same as working as root?

Tags: linux, root

I thought that using su as a regular user made you root temporarily, but encountered an issue where I get "bash: usermod: command not found" when I try to perform a usermod with su, whereas the command definitely exists when I log in as root.

Are super user and root different things? If so, what limitations should I be aware of?

Comment: sudo is there to protect you from yourself as it is too easy to make mistakes running as root. I've been a unix-head since way before sudo, never make an `rm` I didn't mean, and still use sudo in preference to a root shell. Typing 4 characters, a space, and sometimes my user password requires far more awareness of root privilege than having `#` as a shell prompt.

Comment: @msw: true, but sometimes `sudo` is unnecessarily inconvenient, e.g. when you're going to be running a series of commands as `root` or you want to take advantage of filename completion in `rwx------` directories, or something like that. What I do is set the root shell prompt to display in red and my regular user's shell prompt to display in green. Works great and it's pretty too ;-) (and I do _usually_ use `sudo` too)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no difference between "the super user" and "root". But the thing is, `su` (which actually stands for "switch user", I believe) doesn't entirely emulate the environment you would get if you logged in directly as root. For instance, usually when you run `su`, environment variables from your current shell are carried over to the subshell in which you're logged in as root. (Except for `PATH`; see [the man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?su) for details)

To get around this, you can use the `-l` (or `--login`) option to `su`, which will attempt to duplicate the environment you would get if you actually logged in as root.

Comment: +1, right answer. I typically use just the dash instead: `su -`. Check your su man page to verify that `su -` and `su -l` act the same on your system.

Comment: +1 for switch user. Not many people remember that it can be used for any username if you're in wheel.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: regarding `/in wheel/` - does any `su` check that? (I know GNU version ignores `wheel` completely.)

Comment: I honestly don't know. I think that in Solaris it does, but I can't test it at the moment. I remember I read that back when GNU su was new, rms decided not to use wheel because of ideological reasons. I assume that at the time Unix systems regularly checked to see if user was in wheel. Also I read somewhere that Solaris will use wheel if group exists. Here's a source for that http://www.windowsecurity.com/whitepapers/Armoring_Solaris.html

Comment: I also read that BSDs have wheel, but again I haven't used BSD in quite a while, so I don't remember. Here's an article discussing that:  http://administratosphere.wordpress.com/2007/07/19/the-wheel-group/ Here it's said that OS X had wheel at one time http://osxfaq.com/Tutorials/LearningCenter/AdvancedUnix/ugp/index.ws Here's an article about wheel in FreeBSD http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/securing-freebsd.html
In the end, it's good to keep wheel in mind even if the system doesn't support it. You'll never know when you'll stumble upon a system with configured wheel.

Comment: I seem to remember at least one instance of being unable to use `su` until I added my user to `wheel`, and this was on GNU/Linux. (I guess it _might_ have been `sudo` I'm thinking of)

Comment: Can someone expound on the purpose of wheel? I've never used it, my users aren't in it though they have su/sudo rights, but my distro (Fedora core 8) comes with it as a group with root inside.  What is it for?

Comment: @David Is there an equivalent of the -l option for sudo, or would that not make sense (Probably not I'm guessing)

Comment: @Yarin: actually there is: `sudo -i` will simulate an initial login by invoking the shell of the specified user (root by default) as a login shell. This should have mostly the same effect as `su -l` but it's a different mechanism, so it might not be exactly the same down to every detail. See the man page for `sudo` for details.